# Permissions for individual columns of a database table in django?

Tags: django, database, django-models

I have a large database table with many columns. Something like this:

```
+------------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
| postalcode | stat1 | stat2 | ... | stat70 |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
| V0A1A1     | 0.1   |    10 | ... |    100 |
| V0A1A2     | 0.4   |    20 | ... |    300 |
| V0A1A3     | 0.2   |    40 | ... |    200 |
| ....       | ...   |   ... | ... |    ... |
| Z9Z9Z9     | 0.3   |    30 | ... |    400 |
+------------+-------+-------+-----+--------+
```

My django app currently gives all users access to all of the columns, via simple SQL queries.

I want to be able to access the data through the Django API, and in particular I want to be able to give specific users permissions to some columns in the table and not others.

How should I approach this in terms of django models?

Should I make each column a distinct model, with a corresponding table? That would be a lot of models, and a lot of tables!

Or should I create a single model for the entire table? That would be a lot of fields! And how would I handle linking users to fields?

Or should I not create a django model for the table at all, and instead create a meta model that tracks permissions for the table columns, and use that to in some way mediate SQL queries to data table?

```
+------+--------+------------+
| user | column | permission |
+------+--------+------------+
| 1    | stat1  | true       |
| 2    | stat1  | false      |
| 2    | stat2  | false      |
| 3    | stat1  | true       |
| 1    | stat3  | false      |
| ...  | ...    | ...        |
| 100  | stat70 | true       |
+------+--------+------------+
```

That doesn't seem very django-y somehow.

I'm hoping there might be a cleaner, more django solution to this, but it's not occurring to me. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution highly depends on how "fragmented" the permissions will be. If there are just a few Usergroups who each may have access to a distinct set of columns, you can put these columns into several models.

If permissions can be highly individual and you usually require data from all 70 columns or a varying combination thereof, keep it in one table (also to avoid dozens of joins) and include a permission model like you described.

The [`django.contrib.auth.permissions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) should give you already what you need: create 70 Permission-objects, one for each column, and map them either to individual users or to usergroups (depending on the grade of individuality of your permission-vectors)

Comment: Thanks ascripter! My situation is definitely the 2nd one you describe--highly granular, user specific (or at least it might become so, so I need to plan for it).